# How to add dict to dataframe with key name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame('variant':['lamin', 'chromo'],'glassName':['chrome', 'black'],'Type':['low', 'high']'})
```

I want a dict for all values of dataframe in dataframe col:

```
{{"fetch" : [{"name" : "variant" , "value" : "lamin"},{"name" : "glassName" , "value" : "chrome"},{"name" : "Type" , "value" : "low"}]}}
```

```
{{"fetch" : [{"name" : "variant" , "value" : "chromo"},{"name" : "glassName" , "value" : "black"},{"name" : "Type" , "value" : "high"}]}}
```

Comment: There is always one row?

Comment: there are many rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need nested list and dictionary comprehensions for list of values:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'variant':['lamin', 'chromo'],
                 'glassName':['chrome', 'black'],'Type':['low', 'high']})
```

---

```
L = [{"fetch" : [{"name":k,'value':v} for k, v in x.items()]} for x in d.to_dict('records')]
```

---

```
print (L[0])
{'fetch': [{'name': 'variant', 'value': 'lamin'}, {'name': 'glassName', 'value': 'chrome'}, {'name': 'Type', 'value': 'low'}]}
print (L[1])
'value': 'low'}]}
{'fetch': [{'name': 'variant', 'value': 'chromo'}, {'name': 'glassName', 'value': 'black'}, {'name': 'Type', 'value': 'high'}]}
```